# Monitor a rake task in rails 5

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, infinite-loop, rake-task, monit

I have a requirement wherein I have to constantly fetch messages from AWS-SQS(simple queue service) and update the related records of a model. The message contains data that needs to be displayed to the related users as notifications as soon as they are fetched. This has been successfully managed by using Action Cable. I have created a rake task that fetches the messages from the queue and does the required processing. This task is supposed to run in an infinite loop. I have 2 questions regarding it?

```
namespace :sqs_consumer do
  desc 'Get data from the AWS-SQS and process it.'
  task start: :environment do
    # initialize the sqs client
    loop do
      #read the queue for messages and process them in batches(if any)
    end
  end
end
```

1) Is it right to create a rake task for the above requirement? A rake task that runs infinitely is the right way? If not, what is the right approach. I cant run the task periodically since i need data in real time.

2) I want to monitor the task. I am using monit for the same. Unfortunately, Monit conf for the same doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong or missing?

```
check process aws_sqs_consumer with pidfile /var/www/myproject/shared/pids/sqs_consumer.pid
  start program = "/bin/sh -c 'cd /var/www/myproject/current; nohup bundle exec rake sqs_consumer:start RAILS_ENV=staging -i 0 -P /var/www/myproject/shared/pids/sqs_consumer.pid >> log/sqs_consumer.log 2>&1 &'" as uid ubuntu and gid ubuntu
  stop program = "/bin/sh -c 'kill $(cat /var/www/myproject/shared/pids/sqs_consumer.pid)'" as uid ubuntu and gid ubuntu
```

Comment: You could try instead using the daemons gem to create a daemonized process and use God to monitor it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This monit configuration worked for me

```
check process aws_sqs_consumer with pidfile /var/www/myproject/shared/tmp/pids/sqs_consumer.pid
  start program = "/bin/sh -c 'cd /var/www/myproject/current && BACKGROUND=y PIDFILE=/var/www/myproject/shared/tmp/pids/sqs_consumer.pid LOG_LEVEL=info bundle exec rake sqs_consumer:start RAILS_ENV=staging'"
  stop program = "/bin/sh -c 'kill $(cat /var/www/myproject/shared/tmp/pids/sqs_consumer.pid)'" as uid ubuntu and gid ubuntu with timeout 90 seconds
```